# Deleting a user in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

kyler decides to delete his account. Loop through your array of
objects until you find kyler's account - use kyler@test.com to find him in the array.
Once you find the particular index he's located in, delete him from the array.

```
var users = [{
          name: 'talon',
          email: 'talon@test.com',
          password: 'test1234',
          username: 'tdog',
        },{
          name: 'lauren',
          email: 'lauren@test.com',
          password: 'admin1234',
          username: 'ldogg',
        },{
          name: 'cohen',
          email: 'cohen@test.com',
          password: 'baby1234',
          username: 'cdoggy',
        },{
          name: 'kyler',
          email: 'kyler@test.com',
          password: 'delete1234',
          username: 'kdawg'
        }];
```

This is what I have so far, but I am spinning my wheels:

```
        function deleteUser(arr)
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (arr.indexOf([i]) === 'kyler@test.com') {
                users.slice(arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

I am not sure if each of my users needs a variable assigned in the array or if it is my slice. Any guidance would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Just for clarification: Your if statement is wrong. First of all the indexOf method returns the index of an object and then you compare a number with the email string. Additionally you use [i], so you are looking for the index of an array containing the value of i which most definitely will return -1 since it won't find it in your array. The next problem is your slice call. slice returns a new array so let your function return it. Instead I would advice you to use splice like @Yury Tarabanko suggested. Nevertheless you should note that you don't call slice with an object but with the index i.

Comment: @Urknecht Thank you for your explanation. That helps me wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to mutate original array you need [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
function deleteUser(arr, email) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if(arr[i].email === email) {
       arr.splice(i, 1)
       return;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, logically that makes sense. I appreciate it @Yury.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the if statement would be always `false` since [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) method returns an integer value and you are comparing it with a string  using `===` so statement would be always `false`(type mismatch). And the second thing is [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method will not update the existing array it just makes a shallow copy of the array.

To make your own code to work do,

1. Change if condition to `arr[i].email === 'kyler@test.com'`
2. Remove element using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method,  `users.splice(i,1);`.
3. After removing the element break the for loop by using `break`.

---

Final code :

```
 function deleteUser(arr)
   for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i].email === 'kyler@test.com') {
        users.slice(i, 1);
        break;
     }
   }
 }
```

---

Use **[`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)** and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** methods. Where **[`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)** can be used for getting the element index (for older browser use simple loop to get the index) and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method for removing it using the index.

```
users.splice(users.findIndex(function(v) {
  return v.email == 'kyler@test.com'
}), 1);
```

```js
var users = [{
  name: 'talon',
  email: 'talon@test.com',
  password: 'test1234',
  username: 'tdog',
}, {
  name: 'lauren',
  email: 'lauren@test.com',
  password: 'admin1234',
  username: 'ldogg',
}, {
  name: 'cohen',
  email: 'cohen@test.com',
  password: 'baby1234',
  username: 'cdoggy',
}, {
  name: 'kyler',
  email: 'kyler@test.com',
  password: 'delete1234',
  username: 'kdawg'
}];

users.splice(users.findIndex(function(v) {
  return v.email == 'kyler@test.com'
}), 1);

console.log(users);
```

---

**FYI :** For older browser check [polyfill option of `findIndex` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

---

**UPDATE :** Or much faster and old browser supported version using a simple `while` loop;

```
var len = users.length;
// iterate upto `0`
while (len--) {
  // check the email  value
  if (users.email == 'kyler@test.com') {
    // if true then remove the element and break the while loop
    users.splice(len, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

```js
var users = [{
  name: 'talon',
  email: 'talon@test.com',
  password: 'test1234',
  username: 'tdog',
}, {
  name: 'lauren',
  email: 'lauren@test.com',
  password: 'admin1234',
  username: 'ldogg',
}, {
  name: 'cohen',
  email: 'cohen@test.com',
  password: 'baby1234',
  username: 'cdoggy',
}, {
  name: 'kyler',
  email: 'kyler@test.com',
  password: 'delete1234',
  username: 'kdawg'
}];

var len = users.length;
while (len--) {
  if (users[len].email == 'kyler@test.com') {
    users.splice(len, 1);
    break;
  }
}


console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thanks you! This helps a lot.

Comment: @TalonHughes :  glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find at what index is an element within an array by provided testing function (where in your case you will check for `email` property).
Use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove your object at that specific index.

Example below, as you can see User with a that specific email has been removed from the original array:

```js
var users = [{
  name: 'talon',
  email: 'talon@test.com',
  password: 'test1234',
  username: 'tdog',
}, {
  name: 'lauren',
  email: 'lauren@test.com',
  password: 'admin1234',
  username: 'ldogg',
}, {
  name: 'cohen',
  email: 'cohen@test.com',
  password: 'baby1234',
  username: 'cdoggy',
}, {
  name: 'kyler',
  email: 'kyler@test.com',
  password: 'delete1234',
  username: 'kdawg'
}];

var removeUser = function(data, email) {
  var index = data.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.email === email;
  });
  data.splice(index, 1);
};
removeUser(users,'kyler@test.com');
console.log(users);
```